# PHP MYSQL error for android app

Tags: php

What am I doing wrong?

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?wmsAuthSign=, n.channel_description, c.c' at line 6302

```
    private function get_posts() {

        include "../includes/config.php";
        $setting_qry    = "SELECT * FROM tbl_fcm_api_key where id = '1'";
        $setting_result = mysqli_query($connect, $setting_qry);
        $settings_row   = mysqli_fetch_assoc($setting_result);
        $api_key    = $settings_row['api_key'];

        if (isset($_GET['api_key'])) {

            $access_key_received = $_GET['api_key'];

            if ($access_key_received == $api_key) {

                if($this->get_request_method() != "GET") $this->response('',406);
                $limit = isset($this->_request['count']) ? ((int)$this->_request['count']) : 10;
                $page = isset($this->_request['page']) ? ((int)$this->_request['page']) : 1;

                $offset = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
                $count_total = $this->get_count_result("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT n.id) FROM tbl_channel n");

                $query = "SELECT distinct 
                            n.id AS 'channel_id',
                            n.category_id,
                            n.channel_name, 
                            n.channel_image, 
                            n.channel_url?wmsAuthSign=<?php echo $base64urlsignature;?>,
                            n.channel_description,

                            c.category_name

                        FROM 
                            tbl_channel n, 
                            tbl_category c 

                        WHERE 
                            n.category_id = c.cid ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";

                $post = $this->get_list_result($query);
                $count = count($post);
                $respon = array(
                    'status' => 'ok', 'count' => $count, 'count_total' => $count_total, 'pages' => $page, 'posts' => $post
                );
                $this->response($this->json($respon), 200);

            } else {
                die ('Oops, API Key is Incorrect!');
            }
        } else {
            die ('Forbidden, API Key is Required!');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ummmm I bet you **dont** have a column called `n.channel_url?wmsAuthSign=<?php echo $base64urlsignature;?>` But you probably have one called `n.channel_url,`

Comment: Yes, that is right. And what I am trying to do is make the end of every n.channel_url add ?wmsAuthSign=<?php echo $base64urlsignature;?> base64 is generated by this code: $today = gmdate("n/j/Y g:i:s A");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$key = "defaultpassword";
$validminutes = 20;
$str2hash = $ip . $key . $today . $validminutes;
$md5raw = md5($str2hash, true);
$base64hash = base64_encode($md5raw);
$urlsignature = "server_time=" . $today ."&hash_value=" . $base64hash. "&validminutes=$validminutes";
$base64urlsignature = base64_encode($urlsignature);

Comment: I think the answer is _You cannot update the table in a SELECT query_ But now I am even more confused that before

Comment: channel url ends in .m3u8 and needs a signature to work that changes at every refresh and expires every 20 minutes. here it is explained: https://wmspanel.com/paywall/hotlink_protection - how do I add this to the end of every channel url name?

Comment: Maybe `n.channel_url.$base64urlsignature,`

Comment: tried but it doesn't generate the key

Comment: I was going to say I dont see anywjere where you generate that value. So do that just before the `$query =`

Comment: where exactly? https://pastebin.com/rF6Duan9

Comment: `private function get_posts($base64urlsignature) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
REPLACE(n.channel_url, '?wmsAuthSign=', '?wmsAuthSign=".$base64urlsignature."') as channel_url,
```

UNDER                             n.channel_image,